# $ function that toggles elements depending on height of the container that it is in

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, math, responsive

I have this function that needs to show the number of rows depending on the height of the #recent container.

Let's say we don't know the height of the #recent but the height of a .row is const 34px. The thing is that we need to hide all the rows that are nth-child(n+ depends on the number ).

Let's say that if #recent is 100px height we need to show only 2 rows ( becouse if we show 3 the height needs to be more then 102 px)

```
var thisFunc= function() {

    var h = $('#recent').height();
    var nr = Math.round(parseInt(sectionHeight) / parseInt($('.row').height()));

    var x = nr - 1;
    var nth = $('.row:nth-child(n+'+x+')');
    nth.addClass('hideMe');

}

thisFunc();
$(window).resize(thisFunc);
```

We are showing now only the needed amount of rows. But **the issue is when we increase the size of the window they don't appear back**. They have 'hideMe' class added and I'm not sure how to **toggle** it.

Any ideas? Thank You!

Comment: I have probably not understood your use case completely. So the point is to hide (I assume to avoid scrolling or something) extra rows, but in your initial 'round of hiding' you hide based on sectionHeight (is this a constant?) and you want to use the containers new height (variable h in your code?) on window resize right? Would you mind sharing the markup and css for that? It might be that just removing the class wont be enough based on your scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var thisFunc= function() {
// reset childs
$('.row').removeClass('hideMe');


var h = $('#recent').height();
var nr = Math.round(parseInt(sectionHeight) / parseInt(

$('.row').height()));

    var x = nr - 1;
    var nth = $('.row:nth-child(n+'+x+')');
    nth.addClass('hideMe');

}
```